# Named route in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am playing with Rails 4 in a test application. I have an arbitrary URL that isn't standard like a `resources :foo` type URL. Ideally the end result I'd like is to be able to go to:

`/contests/:id/enter`

In views, it would be great if I can then set a link using a named helper such as:

`edit_contests_enter(:id)`?

What would be the best way to define the route above so I can use the helper path with an arbitrary URL like the one above? It doesn't necessarily have to be `edit_contests_enter(:id)` but as long as the helper path leads to the URL as suggested above, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your contest is a resource, and when your visitor goes to `/contests/:id/enter` you want them to create an object `user <=> contest`. Let's call it `participation`.

Now `participation` is exactly like any other resource in your Rails app, so you'd have a `routes.rb` file looking like

```
resources :contests do 
  resources :participations
end
```

You don't want people to do anything other than create a participation, like edit or destroy them. And perhaps you want a nice URI like `/contests/:id/enter`. All you have to do is

```
resources :contests do 
  resources :participations, :only => [:new, :create]
  get "enter" => "participations#new"
end
```

Doing such will give you a routes helper named `contest_enter`. In your `participations#new` form, you'll `POST` as usual to `/contests/:id/participations`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `resources` block for `:contests`, you could just define a new "member" route on the ContestsController using:

```
resources :contests do
  member do
    get :enter
  end
end
```

And that would automatically generate you a named [member route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions), the name of which you could find by running `rake routes`.